# c++ google drive api Uploads untitled file

Tags: c++, google-drive-api, winhttp

I insert the following paremeters using WinHTTP. The files get uploaded successfully but with the title untitled file.

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?access_token=918230812390812038389 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary"
Content-Length: 20176    

--boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "title": "test2.pdf"
}

--boundary
Content-Type: application/pdf

PDF CONTENTS

--boundary--
```

Comment: There appear to be gaps after your content, is that correct? What you are doing should work. I made a small test but cannot reproduce.